# extracting the vector from a data frame

Tags: r

```
usedcars[1:4,16]

[[1]]
[1] "Hyundai" "Verna"   "1.6"     "SX"     

[[2]]
[1] "Hyundai" "i10"     "Era"    

[[3]]
[1] "Volkswagen"  "Polo"        "Petrol"      "Comfort-line" "1.2L"       

[[4]]
[1] "Maruti" "Wagon"  "R"      "LXI"
```

How can i extract only Brand

Earlier i have name column where i have used string_split and split into vector now i need to extract accordingly ?

Comment: This does not compute, your command suggests a data frame, but your output suggests a list, which is it? Share a sample of your data using `dput`.

Comment: dput(usedcars$Name1[c(1,2,3,4)])  output-
list(c("Hyundai", "Verna", "1.6", "SX"), c("Hyundai", "i10", 
"Era"), c("Volkswagen", "Polo", "Petrol", "Comfortline", "1.2L"
), c("Maruti", "Wagon", "R", "LXI"))

Comment: Earlier the name column is having     "Hyundai Verna 1.6 SX"  i have used str_split(),it has stored as vectors

Comment: To return only the first element of each vector, you can use `purrr::map(usedcars[1:4,16], first)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

usedcars <-
    list(c("Hyundai", "Verna", "1.6", "SX"),
         c("Hyundai", "i10", "Era"),
         c("Volkswagen", "Polo", "Petrol",
           "Comfortline", "1.2L" ),
         c("Maruti", "Wagon", "R", "LXI"))


#as a character vector
#equivalent to c(usedcars[[1]][[1]], usedcars[[2]][[1]], usedcars[[3]][[1]], usedcars[[4]][[1]])
map_chr(usedcars, ~.[[1]])
#> [1] "Hyundai"    "Hyundai"    "Volkswagen" "Maruti"

#or ouput as a df
map_df(usedcars,~ c(brands = .x[[1]]))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 1
#>   brands    
#>   <chr>     
#> 1 Hyundai   
#> 2 Hyundai   
#> 3 Volkswagen
#> 4 Maruti

#or finally as another list

map(usedcars, ~ `[[`(.x, 1))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Hyundai"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Hyundai"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "Volkswagen"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "Maruti"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could use `lapply` to extract the first element of each list which appear to be the brand :

```
brand=lapply(usedcars, `[[`, 1)
```

And after you can enlist it if you want :

```
unlist(brand)
```